# Unpacking stack objects (such as structs) using "if let"

Tags: optimization, struct, swift

This is rather a Swift compiler optimization question about the Swift optional stack object (such as struct) and "if let".

In Swift "if let" provides you a syntactic sugar to work with optionals.
What about the structs that live on the stack? As a c++ programmer, I would not introduce an unnecessary copy of a stack object, especially, only in order to check it's presence in the container. Is the struct being copied with all it's members recursively every time you use "if let", or the swift compiler is optimized enough to create a local variable by reference or using other tricks?

For example, we have this struct packaged into an optional:

```
struct MyData{
    var a=1
    var b=2
    //lots more store....

    func description()->String{
        return "MyData: a="+String(a)+", b="+String(b)
    }
}
var optionalData:MyData?=nil
optionalData=MyData()
```

since the struct is on the stack, to unpack, is there an unnecessary copy from the container optionalData to local var data, or the fact that the data is a constant, the copy is optimized away?

```
if let data=optionalData{//is data copy or reference?
    println(data.description())
}
```

Comment: Copying two integers is laughable. Getting a reference may very well be "slower" because it'll have to dereference (and hence "copy") anyway to get the fields. And this is before even considering optimizations which should have an easy time eliding the copies, and perhaps eschew the stack completely (storing the fields in separate registers). C++ expertise is of little use for performance estimation when it's based on a naive abstract machine instead of a reasonable model of *actual* computers and compilers.

Comment: Do we know the struct is on the stack (and not in heap memory)?

Comment: swift struct instances are always on the stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since the struct is on the stack, to unpack, is there an unnecessary copy from the container optionalData to local var data, or the fact that the data is a constant, the copy is optimized away?

It is unlikely that the compiler is actually emitting code to make a copy. `let` essentially gives another name to an expression.

With classes, "let x = y" will allow you to write through your copy of x (because you are just copying a *reference*), i.e.

```
let x = y
x.foo = bar
y.foo // => bar
```

but with structs, this is not the case. You aren't allowed to write to a `let` struct or call any `mutable` methods on it. This allows the Swift compiler to treat `let x = y`, where y is a struct, as a no-op.

However, this code probably does make a copy of `y`:

```
y.foo = bar
let x = y
y.foo = baz
x.foo // => bar
```

It has to, because you wrote to the thing you were copying from. This is known as "copy-on-write", and it's an optimization that's made possible by using `let` semantics.

To answer your final question:

```
if let data=optionalData{//is data copy or reference?
    println(data.description())
}
```

data is assuredly a reference in this case. Actually it probably does not exist at all; the compiler is going to emit the same code as if you wrote:

```
if (optionalData != nil)
{    
    println(optionalData!.description())
}
```